# How to update multiple form elements with ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, json

I need to update the form divs after an ajax was successfully called via jQuery. There're some form elements on my page. And I'd like to fill it with the values sent back from ajax call. Which is in json format.

While ***#inst_name*** is an input[type=text] in which doing 2 things.

1. As an autocomplete input via jquery autocomplete.
2. As a name reference for mysql query in this script.

**HTML :**

```
<input type="text" name="inst_name" id="inst_name" />


<form method="post" action="">
<textarea name="inst_addr" id="inst_addr"></textarea>
<select name="inst_prov" id="inst_prov">
<option value="1">Bangkok</option>
<option value="2">Chiang Mai</option>
<option value="3">Samui</option>
<option value="4">Phuket</option>
</select>



<input type="text" name="inst_tel" id="inst_tel" />
<input type="text" name="inst_fax" id="inst_fax" />


<label><input type="radio" name="inst_dep" id="inst_dep1" value="1" />Dep 1</label>
<label><input type="radio" name="inst_dep" id="inst_dep2" value="2" />Dep 2</label>
<label><input type="radio" name="inst_dep" id="inst_dep3" value="3" />Dep 3</label>
</form>
```

**jQuery :**

```
$('#inst_name').keyDown(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: 'inc/form_institute.json.php',
        dataType:'json',
        data: {name:$('#inst_name').val()},
        success: function(data){
            $('#inst_addr').html(data.addr);
            $('#inst_prov').val(data.prov);
            $('#inst_zip').val(data.zip);
            $('#inst_tel').val(data.tel);
            $('#inst_fax').val(data.fax);
            $('#inst_dep').val(data.dep);
        }
    });
});
```

**JSON :**

```
{
"addr":"123/4 Kitty Ave.",
"prov":"80",
"zip":"12345",
"tel":"0753245675",
"fax":"075123456",
"dep":"2"
}
```

Comment: There's blur, focus, keypress, keyup, keydown, input, paste etc... what event you subscribe to depends on what behaviour you want ?

Comment: @Wilf, and change as well. Try $('#inst_name').change(....

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
$(document).on("keyup", "#inst_name", function(){
    //you're ajax here
}
```

That way the more you type the more specific the response will be.

Good luck :)

Comment: hatzaviv, sorry no luck (-- ")

Comment: Is the function being fired? Is the problem that the fields values aren't changing? Maybe the JSON you receive contains more than just one object in which case you have to choose which object values to display.

Comment: hatzaviv, yes it is triggered by blur()

Comment: and if you try: 
    $('#inst_name').keyup(function(){
    
    });

Comment: I've tried hatzaviv. But it worse than blur. Because it searchs every key press. Saying I have 10 characters it searches 10 times.